# Fatal Error Index Out Of Range ( Swift 2.3 )

Tags: ios, swift, crash, runtime-error, fatal-error

When i run my project i get `Fatal error: Index Out Of Range` and i can't find a solution for it.

I would appreciate some help,Thank you in advance!

**Here is my code :**

```
import UIKit

    // MARK : Data

    var names = ["Shalvata",
                 "Markid",
                 "Litzman Bar",
                 "The Cat & The Dog",
                 "Light house",
                 "Ku"]

    var streets = ["האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב",
                   "אבן גבירול 30,תל אביב",
                   "רחוב נמל תל אביב",
                   "קרליבך 28,תל אביב",
                   "האנגר 23,נמל תל אביב",
                   "דרך שלמה 117,תל אביב"]

    var images = [UIImage(named: "Shalvata"),
                  UIImage(named: "Markid"),
                  UIImage(named: "Litzman Bar"),
                  UIImage(named: "CatNDog"),
                  UIImage(named: "LightHouse"),
                  UIImage(named: "Ku")]

    /////////MARK : END Of Data ! ///////////

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        allUsers = createUsers(names: names, streets: streets, images: images)

        filteredUsers = allUsers

            }

    var allUsers: [User]!
    var filteredUsers: [User]!

    func createUsers(names names: [String], streets: [String], images: [UIImage?]) -> [User] {
        var users = [User]()
        guard names.count == streets.count && names.count == images.count else { return users }
        for (index, name) in names.enumerate() {
            let user = User(name: name, streetName: streets[index], image: images[index])
            users.append(user)
        }
        return users
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //Search:

        if tableView == self.tableView {

            return self.names.count     
        } else {
            return self.filteredUsers.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        cell.photo.image = user.image
        cell.name.text = user.name
        cell.streetName.text = user.streetName

        return cell

    }
}
```

**I get the error in the line:**

`let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]`

**Error line:**

`Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x10033ddc0)`

if anything else is needed just say so,I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3,
I recently started coding so i am a beginner, Sorry for that ;P

Comment: I think that the if in `numberOfRowsInSection` returns `self.names.count` and not `self.filteredUsers.count`. So your tableView has more rows than you have data in filteredUsers.

Comment: Thank you for commenting and Helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both arrays can have different number of elements at the same time. So you need add a condition inside below method to access user based upon tableview.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let user:User!

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        user = allUsers[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.photo.image = user.image
    cell.name.text = user.name
    cell.streetName.text = user.streetName

    return cell
}
```